# syntax error SQL Access Nested IIF ISNULL statements

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax-error, isnull, iif-function

I'm getting a syntax error, I've changed it multiple times, re-typed it and tried to draw a map even. Now after my head is about to expload, out of desperation I'm turning to someone who has an eye for this.

I might be pushing it trying to grab distinct counts of the iif statements, but probably this question is less technical and more about having an eye...

I don't get problems with the FROM/WHERE clauses but they are provided for additional reference.

Please help me if I'm doing something totally wrong:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT(IIF(ISNULL(CombineTables.[Product Description]),

IIF(ISNULL(CombineTables.[Product Number (OEM)]),


IIF(ISNULL(CombineTables.[Product Number (under supplier PA)],"Incomplete Data",CombineTables.[Product Number (under supplier PA)])),

CombineTables.[Product Number (OEM)]),

CombineTables.[Product Description])))
FROM CombineTables WHERE [PA#]=Forms!PADiagnosticsForm!Combo2 AND "QTR." & " " & CombineTables.Quarter & "-" & CombineTables.Year=Forms!PADiagnosticsForm!List68)

FROM CombineTables
WHERE CombineTables.[Price Agreement Price]*CombineTables.Quantity-CombineTables.[Total Extended Price]<>0 And CombineTables.[PA#]=Forms!PADiagnosticsForm!Combo2 And "QTR." & " " & CombineTables.Quarter & "-" & CombineTables.Year=Forms!PADiagnosticsForm!List68;
```

I thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you have success with a simple `IIF` / `ISNULL` combination?

Comment: This is one of the most obscure and convoluted queries I've ever seen.  I have a really hard time reading it or even guessing what is your intent here. Plus, it looks like you have extracted this from another bigger query, there are some things missing, it doesn't look valid (starts with a `(`). Also your `WHERE` clauses have weird things in them, like `"QTR." & " "`, why not simply `"QTR. "` since it's the same thing? Clean up this query first, remove the WHERE clauses or use hard coded values for debugging, then remove everything and construct your SELECT bit by bit, testing it very time.

Comment: The query seems to attempt to treat `DISTINCT` as a function, but it is not a function in Access SQL.

Comment: I apologize, yes it is an incomplete query. There is a leading select statement. Will update shortly.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your query:

1. It is incomplete. The `(` before the first `SELECT` makes it an expression before the second `FROM CombineTables`.  It's therefore missing a leading `SELECT`.  If that's not your full query, then it doesn't help people trying to help you.
2. `NZ(A,B) is identical to and more concise than`IIF(ISNULL(A, B, A))`
3. Your SELECT `COUNT` pattern is suspicious especially with all the `IIF(ISNULL`s.  Because in effect, what is being `COUNT`-ed is never NULL, so you might as well rewrite the entire block in side the `COUNT` as `COUNT(1)`.  `COUNT` unlike SUM does not care about the actual values being counted, it only cares about whether the value is NULL (counted as 0, anything non-NULL counts as 1).